# Steps for Website evaluation

Tags: evaluation

I've been asked to do a website review and evaluation and suggest improvements.

The website is live and running, what should the steps be for this kind of work?

Comment: Is this for a class or training exercise, or is this an instance of the "small team, many hats" problem?

Comment: It's for real, not for a class or training

Answer (score 2):

You might start with a [Heuristic Evaluation](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/). Walk through some typical user workflows paying attention to each of the heuristics on each page. (The link to Nielsen Norman includes links to more documentation.) This is a good first step since it's quick and cheap.

To know what those workflows are, though, you should get to know how users use your site. What are they trying to accomplish? How do they do that? Shadowing (visiting users and quietly observing what they do) is a very useful technique for learning these things.

Comment: Agreed. I would set up a spreadsheet that lists out all of the essential tasks/areas of the website and the heuristics along the top and rate them. Then, ideally, assign 3-5 people to do manual testing and record their results. The result should be a list of weighted issues that you and your team can prioritize them.